# Optional binding syntax in Swift

Tags: swift, option-type

A [tutorial on found I've found helpful](http://lithium3141.com/blog/2014/06/19/learning-swift-optional-types/) un understanding Swift's optional types contains (last example in "Unwrapping" section) the following example:

```
if let y: Int? = someObject.someInt() {
    println(double(y))
} else {
    println("No value to double!") // prints "No value to double!"
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work as intended. Isn't the intent here more like

```
if let y = someObject.someInt() {
    println(double(y))
} else {
    println("No value to double!") // prints "No value to double!"
}
```

These two versions aren't the same, are they? If they're not, I'd like to better understand how each works. In particular: What is the difference between these two pieces of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are different.

for `if let y: Int? = someObject.someInt()`, `y` have type `Int?`, and assignment is always successful so it always execute the first block not the else block even when the return value is `nil`

for `if let y = someObject.someInt()`, `y` is unwrapped first and have type `Int`

```
  1> func foo(a:Int?) -> Int? { return a }
  2> if let y = foo(nil) { println(y) } // can't assign `nil` to Int
  3> if let y = foo(1) { println(y) } // y is Int
1
  4> if let y : Int? = foo(1) { println(y) } // y is Optional<Int>
Optional(1)
  5> if let y : Int? = foo(nil) { println(y) } // it is still executed because it is ok to assign `nil` to `Int?`
nil
```

Comment: That makes sense. I have a [related follow-on question as well](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26170375/656912).

Comment: Also: That means [the tutorial](http://lithium3141.com/blog/2014/06/19/learning-swift-optional-types/) is in error, right?

Comment: Yes, that tutorial is indeed in error, and while it will compile, it will *not* behave as described in that article.