# Equivalence of short-cut optional binding syntax in Swift

Tags: swift, conditional-statements, assign, option-type

Given

```
var maybeInt: Int?
```

how to the following two conditional statements differ?

```
// (1)
if let y = maybeInt {
    y
} else {
    println("Nope")
}

// (2)
if let y = maybeInt? {
    y
} else {
    println("Nope")
}
```

They seem to behave exactly the same. Is the former a short-cut for the latter?

Comment: `maybeInt!` unwrap it and crash if `nil`. I guess `maybeInt?` unwrap it and give you `nil` if `nil`. i.e. doesn't do anything useful

Comment: BTW: I'm not sure about my terms here. "Conditional binding", perhaps?

Comment: it is called [Optional Binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_485)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second syntax is optional *chaining* — just with nothing after the chaining operator. It accesses whatever optional comes before it (if the optional is not `nil`), allows chaining property accesses or method calls on the optional's contents, and wraps the result in an optional. Putting it in an `if let` unwraps that optional.

In other words, the additional `?` in the second syntax is effectively a no-op here.

---

However, though it has no effect in your example, `?` on its own is still doing optional chaining, as you can see with

```
if let y: Int? = maybeInt {
    y
} else {
    println("Nope")
}

if let y: Int? = maybeInt? {
    y
} else {
    println("Nope")
}
```

which results in

```
nil
"Nope"
```

because while `maybeInt? == maybeInt` — a "no op", in the sense above — (and an assignment of `nil` to an `Int?` works) the second expression encounters `nil` on the optional chaining of `maybeInt` and fails.

Comment: Added an example to your answer that really nails it for me. Also, I have a (confused; see [comments on answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26576451/656912) there) [follow-on question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26576366/656912) about when `if let` really unwraps (i.e., when it "looks inside" as the documentations says).